# SSRS custom code and page wise subtotal

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

i want to show per page wise sub total writing custom code.
the output would be like

```
Page 1

Employee Name Salary
------------- -------
keith               2000
Robin               4000
Mou                 3000

Sub Total           9000

Page 2 i mean next page

Employee Name Salary
------------- -------
Markc                1000
Poll                 2500
Sam                  1500

Sub Total            5000
```

i want to declare a shared variable and a function and i need to call my function after each rows render and i will pass the the salary to that function and that function sum the salary and put the output in shared variable which i will display at the table footer. when i will go to next page then shared variable will be re initialize again and hold the sum of salary for that page. if i can do it then per page wise sub total can be shown. i am new in SSRS so i dont know how to associate my function call when each row render......please guide with code and full instruction in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Here Where we Add the **group name.**

1) Show 3 records Per Page by adding a group named "subTotal" and writing following expression:

```
=Ceiling((RowNumber(Nothing)) / 3)
```

2) Add Sub Total Row in tablix

3) Write following expression: